# Error When Fetch data from database SQLite with fragment

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-fragments

This is my fragment activity i am getting error while accessing database my code is :

```
public class RainfallFragment extends Fragment {
public static final String KEY_DIVISION_ID="division_id";
public static final String KEY_DIVISION_NAME="division_name";
ListView listCollege;
ProgressBar proCollageList;
public Context context;
private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;
public RainfallFragment() {}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(getActivity());
   // dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
    dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment


    getActivity().setTitle("Rainfall Report");
    getActivity().setTitleColor(0000000);
    View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rainfall, container, false);
    context = v.getContext();

    v.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    v.requestFocus();
    v.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    getActivity().finish();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    //DISINI BATAS NYA//


    listCollege = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listCollege);
    proCollageList = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.proCollageList);

    new GetHttpResponse().execute();

    listCollege.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2, long arg3) {
            // On selecting single row to get detail information
            final String division_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.adapter_text_id)).getText().toString();
            final String division_name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.adapter_text_estate)).getText().toString();

            AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            b.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
            b.setMessage("Sure for choosing this estate");
            b.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), RainfallReport.class);
                    i.putExtra(KEY_DIVISION_ID, division_id);
                    i.putExtra(KEY_DIVISION_NAME, division_name);
                    getActivity().startActivity(i);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            b.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                }
            });
            b.show();
        }
    });
    return v;
}


private class GetHttpResponse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private Context context;
    String result;
    List<HashMap<String, String>> collegeList;



    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
    {
        List<Estate> estates = new LinkedList<Estate>();
        estates= dbHelper.getAllEstate();

        //Syntax for sort Listview Array by Id Ascending
        Collections.sort(estates, new Comparator<Estate>(){
            @Override
            public int compare(Estate id1,Estate id2) {
                return id1.getDivision_id() - id2.getDivision_id();
            }
        });

        // looping through All data

        for(Estate temp_vg: estates){
            temp_vg.getDivision_id();
            temp_vg.getDivision_name();

            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put("division_id", String.valueOf(temp_vg.getDivision_id()));
            map.put("division_estate", temp_vg.getDivision_name());

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            collegeList.add(map);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)

    {
        proCollageList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        listCollege.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if(collegeList != null)
        {

            //adapter = new ListAdapterEstate(LihatDataEstate.this, map);
            ListAdapterEstate adapter = new ListAdapterEstate(collegeList, context);
            listCollege.setAdapter(adapter);

            //adapter=new LazyAdapter(Lihat_Data.this, dataList);
            //list.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    }
}
```

MySQLiteHelper.java

```
  public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {



    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "AARIDB.db";
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "/mnt/sdcard/AARIDB/DBAARI.db", null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        //super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
          String RAINFALL_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE rainfall ( " +
                "division_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                "year_rainfall VARCHAR (5), "+
                "jan VARCHAR (10), "+
                "feb VARCHAR (10),"+
                "mar VARCHAR (10),"+
                "apr VARCHAR (10),"+
                "may VARCHAR (10),"+
                "jun VARCHAR (10),"+
                "jul VARCHAR (10),"+
                "aug VARCHAR (10),"+
                "sep VARCHAR (10),"+
                "oct VARCHAR (10),"+
                "nov VARCHAR (10),"+
                "dec VARCHAR (10),"+
                " FOREIGN KEY division_id REFERENCES "+ESTATE_TABLE+"division_id;";
        // create table
        db.execSQL(RAINFALL_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older books table if existed

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS rainfall");

        // create fresh books table
        this.onCreate(db);
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * CRUD operations (create "add", read "get", update, delete) book + get all  + delete all
     */


    private static final String TABLE_RAINFALL = "rainfall";
    // assesment Table Columns names
    public static final String KEY_DIVISION_ID_RAINFALL= "division_id";
    public static final String KEY_YEAR_RAINFALL= "year_rainfall";
    public static final String KEY_JAN_RAINFALL = "jan";
    public static final String KEY_FEB_RAINFALL = "feb";
    public static final String KEY_MAR_RAINFALL = "mar";
    public static final String KEY_APR_RAINFALL = "apr";
    public static final String KEY_MAY_RAINFALL = "may";
    public static final String KEY_JUN_RAINFALL = "jun";
    public static final String KEY_JUL_RAINFALL = "jul";
    public static final String KEY_AUG_RAINFALL = "aug";
    public static final String KEY_SEP_RAINFALL = "sep";
    public static final String KEY_OCT_RAINFALL = "oct";
    public static final String KEY_NOV_RAINFALL = "nov";
    public static final String KEY_DEC_RAINFALL = "dec";



    private static final String[] COLUMN_RAINFALL = {
            KEY_DIVISION_ID_RAINFALL,
            KEY_YEAR_RAINFALL,
            KEY_JAN_RAINFALL,
            KEY_FEB_RAINFALL ,
            KEY_MAR_RAINFALL ,
            KEY_APR_RAINFALL,
            KEY_MAY_RAINFALL,
            KEY_JUN_RAINFALL,
            KEY_JUL_RAINFALL,
            KEY_AUG_RAINFALL,
            KEY_SEP_RAINFALL,
            KEY_OCT_RAINFALL ,
            KEY_NOV_RAINFALL ,
            KEY_DEC_RAINFALL};


    public void addRAINFALL(Rainfall rainfall){
        Log.d("addRAINFALL", rainfall.toString());
        // 1. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_DIVISION_ID_RAINFALL, rainfall.getDivision_id()); // get est
        values.put(KEY_YEAR_RAINFALL, rainfall.getYear_rainfall());
        values.put(KEY_JAN_RAINFALL , rainfall.getJan());
        values.put(KEY_FEB_RAINFALL, rainfall.getFeb());
        values.put(KEY_MAR_RAINFALL, rainfall.getMar()); // get estate name
        values.put(KEY_APR_RAINFALL, rainfall.getApr());
        values.put(KEY_MAY_RAINFALL, rainfall.getMay());
        values.put(KEY_JUN_RAINFALL, rainfall.getJun());
        values.put(KEY_JUL_RAINFALL, rainfall.getJul()); // get estate name
        values.put(KEY_AUG_RAINFALL, rainfall.getAug());
        values.put(KEY_SEP_RAINFALL, rainfall.getSep());
        values.put(KEY_OCT_RAINFALL , rainfall.getOct()); // get estate name
        values.put(KEY_NOV_RAINFALL,rainfall.getNov());
        values.put(KEY_DEC_RAINFALL, rainfall.getDec());
        // 3. insert
        db.insert(TABLE_RAINFALL, // table
                null, //nullColumnHack
                values); // key/value -> keys = column names/ values = column values
        // 4. close
        db.close();
    }


    public List<Rainfall> getAllRainfall() {
        List<Rainfall> rainfall = new LinkedList<Rainfall>();
        // 1. build the query
        String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_RAINFALL+" ORDER BY "+KEY_DIVISION_ID_RAINFALL;
        // 2. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        // 3. go over each row, build book and add it to list
        Rainfall rainfall1 = null;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                rainfall1 = new Rainfall();
                rainfall1.setDivision_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                rainfall1.setYear_rainfall(cursor.getString(1));
                rainfall1.setJan(cursor.getString(2));
                rainfall1.setFeb(cursor.getString(3));
                rainfall1.setMar(cursor.getString(4));
                rainfall1.setApr(cursor.getString(5));
                rainfall1.setMay(cursor.getString(6));
                rainfall1.setJun(cursor.getString(7));
                rainfall1.setJul(cursor.getString(8));
                rainfall1.setAug(cursor.getString(9));
                rainfall1.setSep(cursor.getString(10));
                rainfall1.setOct(cursor.getString(11));
                rainfall1.setNov(cursor.getString(12));
                rainfall1.setDec(cursor.getString(13));
                // Add vgm
                rainfall.add(rainfall1);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return rainfall;
    }




    public Cursor getAllDataRainfall() {
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor mCursor = db.query("SELECT year_rainfall, jan, feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug,sep,oct,nov,dec FROM rainfall",
                new String[] {KEY_YEAR_RAINFALL,KEY_JAN_RAINFALL,KEY_FEB_RAINFALL,KEY_MAR_RAINFALL,KEY_APR_RAINFALL,KEY_MAY_RAINFALL,
                KEY_JUN_RAINFALL,KEY_JUL_RAINFALL,KEY_AUG_RAINFALL,KEY_SEP_RAINFALL,KEY_OCT_RAINFALL,KEY_NOV_RAINFALL,KEY_DEC_RAINFALL},
                null, null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        db.close();
        return mCursor;
    }
```

i need database access in fragment only. anybody will help me, and i will appreciate it. the log cat in error is below.

Note! `at com.test.myapplication.RainfallFragment.onCreate(RainfallFragment.java:40)` refers to `dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();`

```
09-14 22:20:16.387 1247-1247/com.test.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.test.myapplication, PID: 1247
                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
                                                                          at com.test.myapplication.RainfallFragment.onCreate(RainfallFragment.java:40)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2068)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1055)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1677)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:536)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Your question implies that the problem is somehow related to accessing the database from your fragment.  Have you confirmed that is the case?  Try accessing the database from elsewhere (Activity, Application class, ...) and see if you get the same error.

Comment: Please edit your question to clearly indicate which line this refers to **`at com.test.myapplication.RainfallFragment.onCreate(RainfallFragment.java:40)`**.  Your TABLE CREATE SQL has errors, it should equate to `CREATE TABLE rainfall (division_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, year_rainfall VARCHAR (5), jan VARCHAR (10), feb VARCHAR (10), mar VARCHAR (10), apr VARCHAR (10), may VARCHAR (10),  jun VARCHAR (10), jul VARCHAR (10), aug VARCHAR (10), sep VARCHAR (10), oct VARCHAR (10), nov VARCHAR (10), dec VARCHAR (10), FOREIGN KEY (division_id) REFERENCES ESTATE_TABLE progress(division_id));` ...

Comment: That is brackets around division_id (both) and a final closing bracket. After fixing you should either, a) uninstall the App, b) clear the App's DATA or c) increase the Version Number and then rerun the App. Not sure if this is the cause though.

Comment: the error is refer to   dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

Comment: The stacktrace is because a null or otherwise invalid Context was passed to SQLiteOpenHelper. The code you posted does not even compile and therefore cannot cause that stacktrace.

Comment: @laalto great to see you're so willing to provide constructive and helpful assistance.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/46231756/2826147 updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I cannot set onCreate of your MySQLiteHelper. You need to put

```
String RAINFALL_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE rainfall ( " +
            "division_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            "year_rainfall VARCHAR (5), "+
            "jan VARCHAR (10), "+
            "feb VARCHAR (10),"+
            "mar VARCHAR (10),"+
            "apr VARCHAR (10),"+
            "may VARCHAR (10),"+
            "jun VARCHAR (10),"+
            "jul VARCHAR (10),"+
            "aug VARCHAR (10),"+
            "sep VARCHAR (10),"+
            "oct VARCHAR (10),"+
            "nov VARCHAR (10),"+
            "dec VARCHAR (10),"+
            " FOREIGN KEY division_id REFERENCES "+ESTATE_TABLE+"division_id;";
    // create table
    db.execSQL(RAINFALL_TABLE);
```

in onCreate of your MySQLiteHelper to create your table like this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String RAINFALL_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE rainfall ( " +
            "division_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            "year_rainfall VARCHAR (5), "+
            "jan VARCHAR (10), "+
            "feb VARCHAR (10),"+
            "mar VARCHAR (10),"+
            "apr VARCHAR (10),"+
            "may VARCHAR (10),"+
            "jun VARCHAR (10),"+
            "jul VARCHAR (10),"+
            "aug VARCHAR (10),"+
            "sep VARCHAR (10),"+
            "oct VARCHAR (10),"+
            "nov VARCHAR (10),"+
            "dec VARCHAR (10),"+
            " FOREIGN KEY division_id REFERENCES "+ESTATE_TABLE+"division_id;";
    // create table
    db.execSQL(RAINFALL_TABLE);         

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I already fix this problem ..
just change my code in RainfallFragment

from:

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> collegeList;
```

to:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> collegeList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

into my Asynctask RainfallFargment .

Answer (score -1):

Change it like in your `MySQLiteHelper` :

```
public class MySQLiteHelper {
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private Context context;
    private DBHelper dbHelper;

    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
            dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);

        }

    public MySQLiteHelper open() throws SQLException {
            db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }

    public void close() {
            dbHelper.close();
       }    

    public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

            public DBHelper(Context context) {
                super(context, "/mnt/sdcard/AARIDB/DBAARI.db", null, 1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                db.execSQL(RAINFALL_TABLE);//create tables
            }

            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS rainfall"); //drop tables if exists and than create or alter
                this.onCreate(db);
            }
        }
}
```

Calling from other `activity` :

```
MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: Incompatible types.
Required: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
Found: com.test.myapplication.MySQLiteHelper :( (Still error)

Comment: Infinite recursion cannot be the answer

Comment: sorry i did not understand that @laalto

Comment: i also didn't understand about your solution @AmitVaghela

Comment: You're proposing to make the constructor create a new object that in turn calls the same constructor again.

Comment: @sasya you didt use context in MySQLiteHelper in contructor due to that you are getting this error

Comment: check my udpated answer@Sasya